# Replacing characters but only if they comply the statement

Tags: c#, string

First of all, I have to tell this that I could find a better title but I just couldn't, just know that I at least tried. Anyways, I'm getting into the issue...

So I have a string pretty much like this:

```
"<aaa+aaa<aaa+aaa><aaa+aaa>><aaa+aaa>"
```

I'm gonna replace "<" to "{", ">" to "}" and "+" to "=." And this would make it like this:

```
"{aaa=aaa{aaa=aaa}{aaa=aaa}}{aaa=aaa}"
```

But I don't want like this one. I want something different which I can't even take it into words, sorry. But pretty sure you'll get when you see it. I want this:

```
"{aaa=aaa<aaa+aaa><aaa+aaa>}{aaa=aaa}"
```

I'm new to C#. I've taken myself into this for hours, really. Even I've come so much closer to success, I still am missing something, therefore, it doesn't work.

I could show my current code here but I think it is basically too long to share with you guys. Leastways, I can say that I used `String.Insert` and `String.Remove` in order to make that. However, it all started confusing and so I decided to tell my story to you.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Some of you wanted a better explanation and more examples. I'm gonna give a few more examples since I'm bad at another one.

```
"<+<+>><+<+><>><+><+<<>>>"
```

to:

```
"{=<+>}{=<+><>}{=}{=<<>>}"
```

**EDIT 2:**
A wonderful person named Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen helped me finding an explanation, thanks:

> I want top-level `<` and `>` to be replaced with `{` and `}`, but nested shouldn't, and `+` to `=` only immediately inside the top-level `<` and `>`, but not inside nested brackets.

Comment: Then **"=" to "+"** actually is **"+" to "="** right?

Comment: @Rafalon Oh sorry, yes it is. I've fixed the question.

Comment: *I can't even take it into words* And we can't make it in code... Better explanation and/or more examples.

Comment: This question looks a lot like you want a to create your own parser

Comment: @xanatos & @P Goslinga No, it won't. I've just added one more example there. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: What does this have to do with Unity?

Comment: And would a better explanation be that you want top-level `<` and `>` to be replaced with `{` and `}`, but nested shouldn't, and `+` to `=` only immediately inside the top-level `<` and `>`, but not inside nested brackets?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Sorry for that! I thought it was about Unity as well since I'm coding for my game being made on Unity. I'm totally new at these so these things happen. Sorry yet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "<aaa+aaa<aaa+aaa><aaa+aaa>><aaa+aaa>";

        int countOpenings = 0;

        // we use a StringBuilder because strings are immutable
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

        for(int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
        {
            // everytime we encounter '<', it's a new opening
            if(sb[i] == '<')
            {
                countOpenings++;
                // if it's the first opening, we change it to '{'
                if(countOpenings == 1)
                {
                    sb[i] = '{';
                }
            }
            // everytime we encounter '>' it means we get out of a block
            else if(sb[i] == '>')
            {
                countOpenings--;
                // if the '>' matches the first opening, we change it to '}'
                if(countOpenings == 0)
                {
                    sb[i] = '}';
                }
            }
            else if(sb[i] == '+' && countOpenings == 1)
            {
                sb[i] = '=';
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, note that this might fail if you have wrongly formatted input strings (e.g. not the same amount of `<` as `>`)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it actually works! I actually did something similar - now trying to clutch what I was missing. Thanks again :)

You needn't mention that anyway. That'd be mine problem, not yours; nevertheless, you're awesome!

Comment: Well, adding your current code to your question might help us figuring out what was wrong with it

Comment: Well, the issue was that I didn't use `StringBuilder` I believe. I'll also share the code when I'm home.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
public static string Transform(string str)
{
    int lvl = 0;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        switch (ch)
        {
            case '<':
                if (lvl == 0)
                {
                    ch = '{';
                }
                lvl++;
                break;
            case '>':
                if (lvl == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Malformed string at pos {i}");
                }
                else if (lvl == 1)
                {
                    ch = '}';
                }
                lvl--;
                break;
            case '+':
                if (lvl == 1)
                {
                    ch = '=';
                }
                break;
        }

        sb.Append(ch);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

In the end you have a level of nesting `lvl`. You want the transformation of `<` to `{` to happen only when you are at `lvl == 0`, and of `>` to `}` only when after the closing the `lvl` will become 0 (so only if you are at `lvl 1`). You want to change `+` to `=` only when you are at `lvl 1`.

Use it like:

```
string str1 = Transform("<+<+>><+<+><>><+><+<<>>>");
string str2 = Transform("<aaa+aaa<aaa+aaa><aaa+aaa>><aaa+aaa>");
```